# How can I tell how good a Ruby gem is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Having a wide choices of gems is one of the strengths of working with Ruby on Rails.

However, it's often not clear how good a gem is.  You can tell how lately it has been updated, how many times it's been downloaded.  But there's no gem ratings (not that I'm aware of).  This seems to be an easy thing to add.

A number of things should be rated: how clear the documentation is, how responsive the
creator is to questions, how soon improvements are merged, etc.

Another thing is how vibrant is the community who uses this gem, how helpful (for enhancing the gem, as well as helping newbies get started using the gem).

Are there forums for each gem for the users to discuss issues, submit sample code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually a good way is going to the ruby toolbox page, where you can see how many people are using it, then going into github, see how active the development is, when the last commit was, the issues (and how fast they are fixed), the pending pull requests, etc.

There is a nice episode that explains a little all the features to explore when looking for a gem: http://railscasts.com/episodes/384-exploring-rubygems

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem in pretty much every language.  [ruby-toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) provides much of what you ask for.  If you click a gem's rating you even get a breakdown of the rating over time and what factors lead to the rating.

An additional problem ruby-toolbox addresses is assigning gems to categories.  What do the names 'Cucumber' or 'Capybara' have to do with testing? Or 'paperclip' with uploads? or 'hpricot' with html parsing? ruby-toolbox lets you click on categories (or search for them) and see what gems may offer the functionality you want.